# Make 3 errors so CRC algorithm will result false positive

Tags: algorithm, networking, crc

Consider the generator polynomial `100101` and the data `1011100110001`. Applying the [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) algorithm we get the transmitted message: `101110011000100011`

I need to make `3` errors in the transmitted message (that is, bit flips) that the receiver won't notice. Hence, the CRC algorithm will fail to notice the errors and will falsely approve the data.

How can this be arranged? trial and error is too tedious.

I have found that for `1011100110010 10010` (`1011100110010b = 5938d` and `10010b = 18d`) we have that `5938 = 18 mod 37`, yet when applying the CRC algorithm on this it fails.

Comment: "_trial and error is too tedious._" You can always write an application to do the trial-and-error for you.

Comment: Arithmetic modulus has nothing whatsoever to do with CRC calculations over GF(2). As noted in the other comment, there are only 13 bits of message, so only 286 possible 3-bit error patterns to try! Just write a program to try all of them and report which have a zero CRC. (Then they can be exclusive-or'ed with any 13-bit message to result in an unchanged CRC.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CRC algorithm can be thought of as reducing the message by XORing with the generator pattern shifted left by some bits.

The CRC test passes if the message reduces to 0.

This means that if you XOR with the CRC shifted left by some bits, the CRC will remain unchanged.  In your case the generator polynomial only has 3 set bits, this makes it easy to find lots of messages with 3 bits modified, simply toggle bits x,x+2,x+5 for any choice of x.

For example we could change

```
101110011000100011 to 
001011011000100011
```

Comment: How is the CRC-left-shifted-message related to toggling of `x,x+2,x+5`?

Comment: `100101` has ones in the bit positions 5, 2, and 0. A shift of that, such as `100101000` has ones in positions x, x+2, and x+5, where in this case x is 3.

Answer (score 1):

Of the 286 possible three-error patterns, there are 11 that have a CRC of zero. They are the eight shifts of the polynomial as noted by Peter de Rivaz, the first being `1001010000000`, and the three shifts of this pattern: `1000001000100`. That pattern is the exclusive-or of three of the shifted polynomials, `1001010000000`, `0001001010000`, and `0000010010100`.